# Partial typedef (`using`) of a templated function

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, c++14, using

Trying to implement a dot product function using templates, I have written the following templated function.

```
template <typename T, typename R = float,
  typename = 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<decltype(std::declval<T>().x)>{}>,
  typename = 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<decltype(std::declval<T>().y)>{}>>
constexpr R dot(const T a_vector, const T b_vector)
{
    return a_vector.x * b_vector.x + a_vector.y * b_vector.y;
}
```

I want my users to also easily use the `dot` function returning a `double` instead of the default `float`. That's why I am using a `using` to "typedef" the `dot()`.

```
template<typename T, typename R, typename ... >
using dotd = dot<T, double>;
```

This code yields

- in g++ *`error: ‘dot<T, float>’ does not name a type`*
- in clang++ *`error: expected a type`* and  *`error: expected ';' after alias declaration`*

Do I have an option to use an alternative for functions?

Comment: type alias can be only created for __types__. Function is not a type.

Comment: @Dundee, yes you do! :) Look at my answer.

Comment: You don't use `R` anywhere yet... Did you mean to use `constexpr R dot(...)`?

Comment: If you still need type deduction, just add a new function

Comment: @Simon Kraemer - that's right. Pasted old code. I'll fix it. The errors stay, however.

Comment: @Nasser sorry for that. Although your question didn't help me, it sorta answered my question. That is true.

Comment: @Vogel612 noted, comment deleted

Comment: @Dundee no problem, I deleted the comment, because I realized I could have provided a better answer. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just flip the ordering of the template arguments. If you place `R` first, it's easy for the user to simply provide a different type for it if that's what they want:

```
template <
  typename R = float,
  typename T,
  typename = 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<decltype(std::declval<T>().x)>{}>,
  typename = 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<decltype(std::declval<T>().y)>{}>>
constexpr R dot(const T a_vector, const T b_vector)
{
    return a_vector.x * b_vector.x + a_vector.y * b_vector.y;
}
```

And then `dot(a, b)` gives you a `float` vs `dot<double>(a, b)` gives you a `double`. I find `dot<double>` a lot clearer than having to look up what `dotd` means.

Though if you're using C++14, better to simply drop the `R` template argument completely and return `auto`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I just thought I could shorten it further to dotd().

Comment: The problem with auto is, it doesn't handle all the types gracefully. Let's say the vectors passed in are of type int. In this case, the dot() function won't return any meaningful value.

Comment: @Dundee Why would the return type not be meaningful? If the `x`s and `y`s are `int`, you'd get `int`. How is that worse than `float`?

Comment: Hell, I just realized, there's no division in the whole thing. LOL, my brain was too tired yesterday, I guess. Thank you for pointing that out, Barry :)

Comment: You don't need a default for `T` at all.

Comment: @T.C. Wow. I... never knew that.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is very simple:

```
template <class T1, class T2> void foo();

template <class T1, class T2> struct FooHelper {
   static constexpr auto foo = &foo<T1, T2>;
};

template <class T>
auto food = FooHelper<T, float>::foo;

void g() {
  food<float>();
}
```

Comment: Why not a variable template?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, because OP needs a specific function, not a templated family of this. (Unless I misunderstand the question).

Comment: then why not `auto food = &foo<double, float>;` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, no reason whatsoever! I was actually thinking of variable templates, started doing it, than realized it is not needed, but class remained in my brain!!! Will edit. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: This does not meet the OP's requirement- the first argument to `food` is no longer templated either.

Comment: OP is clearly missing that with a variable template or any other alias type deduction won't work

Comment: @Puppy, true. Back to the helper with variable template. However, I feel like you are a bit trigger-happy with your downvotes.

Comment: @SergeyA: I wonder too. It's an alternative to the Barry's answer (which, I just realized, solves my problem a bit easier), but since when are alternative solutions downvoted? I am really sorry you got the downvotes, SergeyA.